# How to separate data of different tables from dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, c#-4.0, ado.net

Sir actually I'm getting data from three tables in database. I use a query in database that has inner joins that work fine for me and I populate dataset from that query, but issue is that I want to separate the fields that belong to different table in each record. 
for example: I have a student, teacher and class tables in db. I fetch data using inner joins in between these tables. i populate dataset from that result. Now in front end I want to separate data that belong to separate table, i want student fields separate, teacher fields separate. what should I need to do? what operation require me to perform on dataset to achieve such scenario.

Answer (score 2):

If you use stored procedures you can return 3 differents select statements instead of using joins. You can then access the tables like so:

```
ds.Tables[0].Columns["studentid"]
ds.Tables[1].Columns["classid"]
ds.Tables[2].Columns["teacherid"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new data set which contains the three distinct tables with their correct relations.

If you already have the structure within your database you can within Visual Studio simply click within the menu bar on *Data* - *Add new data source* and select *Database* - *Dataset* in the first wizard dialogs. Afterwards define the connection string and select all the needed tables, views, etc.

When you have finished the wizard you'll get a new dataset containing all the desired tables and their relations to each other. Within the designer you can then open the *Data* - *Show data sources* panel and drag/drop the desired tables onto your form/control and also create quite easily master/detail views.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your data set and since you know your columns that will be the result of your query, you can do something like this.

```
   ds.Tables[0].Columns["student_colummn1"] 
   ds.Tables[0].Columns["student_colummn2"] 
   ds.Tables[0].Columns["student_colummn3"] 

   ds.Tables[0].Columns["teacher_column1"] 
   ds.Tables[0].Columns["teacher_column2"]
   ds.Tables[0].Columns["teacher_column3"]

   ds.Tables[0].Columns["class_column1"] 
   ds.Tables[0].Columns["class_column2"] 
   ds.Tables[0].Columns["class_column3"]
```

If possible look into LINQ, makes your life easier.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`Don't use a dataset.` Define separate classes for student,teacher and class tables. Use your DAL to populate these classes & access them separately in your application.